# cleaning my list

Tags: python, loops, nested-lists

Hello I have a loop which goes counts different records in my MySQL database and then saves the numbers to a list. Here is the list:
`[1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L]`

now I go thru this list and I want to leave only single numbers (means 1L, 2L etc) I'm using this loop:  `for number in legend:
        print number # to check what number it does currently
        counter = legend.count(number)
        while counter > 1:
            legend.remove(number)
            counter -= 1`

then I see that it checks 1,2,3,4,3,2,1 ...why is that? why this loop wont check number 5? at the end the list looks like this:
`[5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L]`

that means it works but why it doesn't go for number 5?

thx in advance

Comment: You are iterating over `legend` and inside the loop you remove elements from it. You should never modify the sequence you are iterating over.

Comment: thx man that makes a sense ^^

Comment: It's not a good way to do it, since you algorithm is O(n^2). The problem you are having is that you are modifying `legend` while you are looping over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put it in a `set`.

```
>>> foo = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,1,4,3,6,5,6]
>>> set(foo)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

This will automatically filter out all duplicates. Maybe you can even skip the list, and put it in a `set` in the first place.

Comment: ehhh it was much easier than expected ^^ I was looking for some other (harder) error... thanks it fixed my issue... will check this answer but need to wait 12 mins to do so ^^

Comment: is there a way to access each of the numbers in set()? it gives me an error that set is unindexable

Comment: @Tomasz: To do this, you have to convert it back to a list: `list(set(legend))`. Keep in mind that this might change the order of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You might fall into problem such as:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
for l in list:
    print "Elem ", l
    if l == 2:
        list.remove(1)
```

which gives output:

```
Elem  1
Elem  2
Elem  4
```

List is modified in loop and while removing some element that you already looped through you are **skipping** one element in list.

Comment: yeah I noticed that... i used "for l in set(list)" and that worked